# why is the second item in a list indented further

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{fullpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{ Calculate the average volume of titrant used.}
    
    \medskip $ V_{Avg} = \frac{8.30 \ mL + 8.25 \ mL + 6.45 \ mL + 7.95 \ mL}{4} = 7.74 \ mL$ \\
    
   
    \medskip \newline  \therefore \text{The average titrant used was 7.74 mL.} 
    
    \item \textbf{Write a balanced chemical equation (including states) for the reaction between acetic
acid and sodium.} 

$ CH_{3}COOH_{ (aq) } + NaOH_{ (aq) } \longrightarrow NaCH_{3}COOH_{ (aq} ) + H_{2}O_{ (l) }$

\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

How can I make it so that the first and second item are in line with each other?

Comment: This code produces numerous errors. If you remove `\newline` the items are aligned, but you need to fix the other errors, too, `\therefore` wants to be in math mode, and `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` instead of `\usepackage[margin=1in]{fullpage}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the alignment issue: there is a mistake in the statement "reaction between acetic
acid and sodium." You probably wanted to write "sodium hydroxide" instead of "sodium". Also, the following reaction is not correct. "NaCH3COOH" is not what forms during the titration of acetic acid with NaOH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code contains multiple errors and inaccuracies. *You disregard error and warning messages at your own peril.*

- The `fullpage` package does not recognize the option `margin=1in`. As @user238301 has already suggested in a comment, it's a good idea to use `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` instead of loading the `fullpage` package
- The `\newline` directive is incorrect. Delete it.
- `\therefore` must occur in math mode.
- The whitespace character in `\textbf{ Calculat` is wrong. Delete it.
- The code block

  ```
  \medskip 
  $ V_{Avg} = \frac{8.30 \ mL + 8.25 \ mL + 6.45 \ mL + 7.95 \ mL}{4} = 7.74 \ mL$ \\
  \medskip
  ```

  is simply *bad*. Very sorry for not being able to sugarcoat the truth. I can only suggest that you learn to use (a) the `siunitx` package for typesetting scientific units and (b) display-math mode and start to to write

  ```
  \[
  V_{\mathrm{Avg}} = \frac{\SI{8.30}{mL} + \SI{8.25}{mL} + \SI{6.45}{mL} + \SI{7.95}{mL}}{4} 
  = \SI{7.74}{mL}
  \]
  ```
- No need to encase "The average titrant..." in a `\text{...}` wrapper.
- There are several packages out there to help typeset chemical equations. I suggest you familiarize yourself with one of them, say, the `mhchem` package, and replace

  ```
  $ CH_{3}COOH_{ (aq) } + NaOH_{ (aq) } \longrightarrow NaCH_{3}COOH_{ (aq} ) + H_{2}O_{ (l) }$
  ```

  with

  ```
  \[
  \ce{CH3COOH_{(aq)} + NaOH_{(aq)} -> NaCH3COOH_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)}}
  \]
  ```

  Doesn't that look *a lot* easier? And the output looks so much better too.
- Not an outright error, but an assault on decent typography: Unless you want to create the impression that you like to **SHOUT** at your readers, there is no discernible reason to render the items' instructions in **bold**.

In sum, here's how I would render your raw material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unless you have a good reason for using 'OT1'
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{fullpage} % option 'margin=1in' not legal
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{siunitx} % <-- new, for '\SI' macro
\usepackage{mhchem}  % <-- new, for '\ce' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Calculate the average volume of titrant used.
\[
V_{\mathrm{avg}} = \frac{\SI{8.30}{mL} + \SI{8.25}{mL} + \SI{6.45}{mL} + \SI{7.95}{mL}}{4} = \SI{7.74}{mL}
\]
$\therefore$ The average titrant used was \SI{7.74}{mL}. 
    
\item Write a balanced chemical equation (including states) for the reaction between acetic acid and sodium.
\[
\ce{CH3COOH_{(aq)} + NaOH_{(aq)} -> NaCH3COOH_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)}}
\]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips! I just learned latex a couple days ago and I'm sure your feedback will help for years to come :)