# new latex user, would appreciate if someone could double check my form

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{mhchem}  
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item {Find the actual (undiluted) concentration of vinegar mol/L.}

\[  C_{NaOH} = \SI{0.120}{mol/L}  , \ V_{NaOH} = \SI{0.00774}{L} \ , \ V_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \SI{0.01}{L} \ , C_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \ ? \]

\[ n_{NaOH} = c \cdot V\]
\[ n_{NaOH} = (\SI{0.120}{mol/L})(\SI{0.00774}{L})\] 
\[ n_{NaOH} = \SI{0.0009288}{mol}\]

\[ n_{CH_{3}COOH} = n_{NaOH} = \SI{0.0009288}{mol} \ (1:1 \ ratio) \]

\[ C_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \frac{n}{V}\]
\[ C_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \frac{\SI{0.0009288}{mol}}{\SI{0.01}{L}}\]

\[ C_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \SI{0.00928}{mol/L}\]

$\therefore$ The actual (undiluted) concentration of vinegar is \SI{0.1}{mol/L}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Incorporated feedback from my first post [why is the second item in a list indented further](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/589024/why-is-the-second-item-in-a-list-indented-further) and just wanted to double check my form :)

Comment: The concentration should be a small c and your calculation is one order of magnitude to low. (Should be 0.09288?!). Also, the superscripts in your equations should not be italic or at least use an uniform style.

Comment: Do you also want to align the equations relative to each other?

Comment: Why didn't you use `\ce{NaOH}`? `Also, you might group equations with the `align*` or `gather*`environment.

Comment: @Excelsior my bad on the miscalculation. would i just use \ce on every subscript to fix the italtic issue? how would i go about aligning the equations relative to each other? thanks

Comment: for the italic issue you can use, as suggested from @Bernard the `\ce{}` synthax and for aligning again as @Bernard stated `align*{}`or `gather*` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example, that you know what I am talking about. You can want to add some space between the equations , ..., but this is the result I was thinking of.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{mhchem}  

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}
    \item {Find the actual (undiluted) concentration of vinegar mol/L.}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $c_{\ce{NaOH}} = \SI{0.120}{mol/L}$
            \item $V_{\ce{NaOH}} = \SI{0.00774}{L}$
            \item $V_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \SI{0.01}{L}$
            \item $c_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \ ?$
        \end{itemize}
        
        \begin{align*}
            n_{\ce{NaOH}} &= c \cdot V \\
            n_{\ce{NaOH}} &= \SI{0.120}{mol/L} \cdot \SI{0.00774}{L} \\
            n_{\ce{NaOH}} &= \SI{0.0009288}{mol} \\
            \frac{n_{\ce{CH3COOH}}}{n_{\ce{NaOH}}} &= \frac{1}{1} \Leftrightarrow n_{\ce{CH3COOH}} = \SI{0.0009288}{mol} \\
            c_{\ce{CH3COOH}} &= \frac{n}{V} \\
            c_{\ce{CH3COOH}} &= \frac{\SI{0.0009288}{mol}}{\SI{0.01}{L}} \\
            c_{\ce{CH3COOH}} &= \SI{0.0928}{mol/L} \\
        \end{align*} 
    
    $\therefore$ The actual (undiluted) concentration of vinegar is \SI{0.1}{mol/L}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!

Comment: No blank line after the `align*`